Muchos intentos de inicio de sesión a la base, MSSQL 2017
Tengo este error 18456 pero por intentos de inicio de sesión externos desde IP desconocidas y luego se bloquea la conexión.
¿Qué puedo hacer para evitar estas conexiones?

Bueno.. para empezar tu db no deberia estar abierta para afuera.. eso como primer paso...

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
